# Is there a JFrame.getBounds equivalent that gets only the actual client area?

Tags: java, swing, dimensions

Instead of the whole window complete with close, maxi- and minimize buttons, as well as border?

I'm trying to save a screenshot of the client area...maximizedBounds crashes the app...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Get the bounds of the content pane instead (i.e. [`JFrame.getContentPane().getBounds()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#getBounds%28%29)).

Comment: that works, but I have to adjust the coordinates of the snapshot, it seems.

Comment: I'm using the Robot to create the snapshot, your approach returns the correct dimensions, but x and y coordinates are both zero, I guess because getBounds returns the position relative to the parent, and that's x0 y0 for the panel. This results in robot taking a screenshot of my desktop that covers 0,0,PanelWidth,Panelheight, which only covers a region of my app, which is in the center of my screen.

Comment: looks like as for that would be required Frame.getXxx +1

Answer (score 5):

This did the trick:

```
   Point pos = this.getContentPane().getLocationOnScreen();
   Rectangle clientRect = this.getContentPane().getBounds(); 
   clientRect.x = pos.x;
   clientRect.y = pos.y;
```

Comment: +1 For explanation in comment to my answer and for providing this answer for further clarification.